# Angular2 server side return value for http delete

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am new to angular2.  I am trying to delete a record.  When I delete, my back server side is passed the id and the record is deleted.

But I get an error from angular but when a refresh data I deleted is no longer present.  So for some reason I get an error .  Maybee because I dont know what I should be returning.

Here is what is in my Component:

```
deleteGit(git:any){
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete " + git.name + "?")) {
            var index = this.gits.indexOf(git)
            // Here, with the splice method, we remove 1 object
            // at the given index.
            this.gits.splice(index, 1);

            this.gitService.deleteGit(git.id)
                .subscribe(null, 
                    err => {
                        alert("Could not delete the user.");
                        // Revert the view back to its original state
                        // by putting the user object at the index
                        // it used to be.
                        this.gits.splice(index, 0, git);
                    });
        }
    }
```

Here is what is in my service:

```
deleteGit(gitId:any){
        return this._http.delete(this.getGitUrl(gitId)).map(res => res.json());
  }
```

In my api server side I am returning:

{"status": true}

I also return status code of 204

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: why pass `null` to subscribe?

Comment: ps if I return status code of 201 the works but I though 204 was for delete